# How to positioning popup on Jquery Mobile?

Tags: mobile, popup, css-position, navbar, popupmenu

I've made a listview menu with using popup (Jquery Mobile), but when the navbar was clicked, the position of popup was displayed to origin. I want my listview menu when it clicked will looks like a dropdown menu. I've set the position on my css and the javascript, but it didn't affect the display. So, could anybody help me to make the display position looks like a dropdown menu?

Here's the screenshoot:

[image menu](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6MtEMbZDsHCUlRCSHV1dnE3aTg/edit)

How to make the popup was below the navbar so it could see like a dropdown?

Here's the css:

```
div#popupMenu{
    float: left;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

I'm using the javascript too, but didn't affect:

```
$( ".selector" ).popup( "open", x:0, y:200 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I am struggling with popup positioning too. I got close using this markup:

```
<!-- menu trigger -->
<a data-icon="gear"
   data-iconpos="notext"
   href="#menu"
   data-rel="popup"
   data-position-to="#menu-anchor"
   data-transition="slidedown">Menu</a>

<!-- menu position helper -->
<div id="menu-anchor"></div>

<!-- menu -->
<div id="menu" data-role="popup">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="/">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The trigger and menu can go anywhere. However, the anchor must go somewhere near the top of the page. jQM tries to align the center of `#menu` with the center of `#menu-anchor` but since the anchor is at the top of the screen it tries to align the top with top of the screen giving you almost expected result.

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/2ArPk/)